# Disadvanage of given Singleton cache patterm

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, singleton

I am using the given singleton pattern to cache a class object in ASP.NET. Can anyone highlight the disadvantages of this approach?

```
public class CacheManager
{
private static CacheManager _instance;

protected CacheManager(string key) { id = key; }
public static CacheManager getInstance(string key)
{
   if (HttpContext.Current.Cache[key] == null)
       HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(key, _instance = new CacheManger(key), null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),CacheItemPriority.Default,new CacheItemRemovedCallback(ReportRemovedCallback));

   return (CacheManager)HttpContext.Current.Cache[key];
}

private static void ReportRemovedCallback(string CacheManager, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
{            
    _instance = null;
}

public string id { get; private set; }        
public string field1 { get; set; }
public string field2 { get; set; }
public string field3 { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I would call this a singleton, per se. It's just a static wrapper over non-static data. This is basically what `HttpContext.Current` does, you're just adding helpers specific to your application. I don't see any problems with this.

Comment: its not thread safe, but even before that - what are you trying to do in the `getInstance` and `ReportRemovedCallback` methods?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason for you to make this a singleton. I would just write a wrapper for each property that gets/sets the values. That way you can inject it much more easily with an IoC container and increase testability.

As it stands now, your code isn't thread safe which could cause problems too.

Comment: How often is more than one thread working with the same instance of `HttpContext.Current` though?

Comment: I'm not concerned about the current context - thats thread local. Its this class. `_instance` isn't guarded.

Comment: @Yuck, why do you think its unlikely there will be more than one thread accessing the `Cache` object? it is shared by the app domain, isnt it?

Comment: @YavgenyP `Cache` is thread safe by design. it's really up to the provider to do that. i'm not sure how asp.net handles it.

Comment: `Cache` might be thread safe (i think it is), but not if you wrap the access to it with an `if..else` statement, so it depends on the the way he handles the keys here. anyway, to me his code doesnt make any sense (i dont understand what `_instance` does, as it seems it gets overriden everytime).

Comment: @YavgenyP i missed that. yea its not used too much. gag. this is why singletons mixing with other singletons suck.